# Grouping and substitution with sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file where some lines are as so:

```
ENV FOO bar
ENV BAZ boz
ENV BIP bop
```

I want to convert those lines only to:

```
export FOO=bar
export BAX=boz
export BIP=bop
```

I have bash at my disposal, and was attempting to achieve it through `sed`, `awk`, etc, but it's Friday afternoon and I'm not all there.

Any suggestions? Closest I've got is:

```
sed -i 's/^ENV\s\([A-Z]\)\s*\([A-Z]\)/export \1 = \2/g' -i file
```

Thanks.

Comment: you need to use the reg exp flag `-r` when dealing with replacement variables `\1` and `\2` and remove the escapes in front and after the match like `([A-Z])`.

Comment: @geert3 i encountered some problems using internal replacement variables `\n` when running w/o `-r`.

Comment: @EmilKakkau sorry you're right on the -r. It's Friday for me too ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a repeater (`*`) on both ranges and lower case in the latter range. And like @EmilKakkau mentioned, you need the `-r` option and don't need the escapes on the brackets.

```
sed -r 's/^ENV\s([A-Z]*)\s*([a-z]*)/export \1 = \2/g' -i file
```

Comment: how could you have a space before and after the `=` that are not in the final result with this sed ? i propose to use `(.*)` instead of `([a-z])` for the variable content

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
awk '$1=="ENV"{printf "export %s=%s%s", $2, $3, ORS}' file
export FOO=bar
export BAZ=boz
export BIP=bop
```

**Explanation:**

```
$1=="ENV"                             # Do it only when first field is ENV
printf "export %s=%s%s", $2, $3, ORS  # print formatted output by inserting =
                                      # between field 2 and field 3
```

Using sed:

```
sed '/^ENV /s/^ENV/export/;s/ \+\([^ ]\+$\)/=\1/' file
export FOO=bar
export BAZ=boz
export BIP=bop
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. The only issue is it also converts lines like this:

WORKDIR /home/dev

into 

WORKDIR=/home/dev

Comment: Are you sure about that? I have `$1=="ENV"` condition that makes sure first field is `ENV`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/ENV/export/;s/\s+/=/2' -i file
```

2 substitution, take any value into account